# Finding solutions of the system $27x + 90 \equiv 18 \pmod{99}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to find solutions for the expression $$27x + 90 \equiv 18 \pmod{99}$$

My only problem is that I can only solve expressions like $ax \equiv  b \pmod{n}$.
How can I get rid of the $90$? Subtracting $90$ from both sides won't work I think because I will have a negative number...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're new here, so I'll make a suggestion, since you've asked a handful of questions today: When you receive an answer that's helpful, we encourage users to *accept* an answer (you can accept only one answer per question). To accept an answer, simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left the the answer you'd like to accept. Plus, you get two reputation points for each answer you accept!

Comment: Negative numbers with moduo are fine as well. They can be really helpful sometimes as well, for example from $3^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$ you can easily calculate $3^n$ modulo $10$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always add or subtract multiples of 99 from either side.

$$27x +90 \equiv 18 \text{ mod 99}$$
$$27x +90-99 \equiv 18 \text{ mod 99}$$
$$27x -9\equiv 18 \text{ mod 99}$$
$$\text{ Now adding 9 to both sides gives,}$$
$$27x \equiv 27 \text{ mod 99}$$
$$\text{And dividing both sides by 9}$$
$$3x \equiv 3 \text{ mod 11}$$
$$\text{ And since 3 is coprime to 11}$$
$$x\equiv 1 \text{ mod 11}$$
$$\text{ From which one can see, $x=1$ is clearly a solution}$$
$$\text{ And for additional solutions just add multiples of 11}$$

Comment: It's worth adding that one can divide the entire equation, including the modulo value, by any factor of the modulo value, to simplify. So you can write $$\frac{27}{9}x\equiv \frac{27}{9} \mod \frac{99}{9}$$, which then becomes $$3x\equiv 3 \mod 11$$, or $$x\equiv 1 \mod 11$$

Comment: is it wrong to say that x = 1 is the only solution?

Comment: $x\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ is the general solution. So if you want positive solutions, then in addition to 1, you also have 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 100, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\quad 90\equiv -9\bmod 99\quad $$

Comment: I don't know, I am a little confused. Does 27x ≡ -72(mod99) equal 27x ≡ 72(mod99) ?

Comment: No (and also, it is incorrect to say that two equations or congruences are equal; what you want to say is, are they *equivalent*). My hint is that because $90\equiv -9\bmod 99$, you know that
$$27x+90\equiv 27x-9\bmod 99,$$
and you say you know how to proceed from a congruence of this form.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $99$, there's no such thing as a negative number. $-100$, $-1$, $98$, and $197$ are all the same thing. Your idea of subtracting 90 from both sides is the thing to do.

Comment: I don't know, I am a little confused. Does 27x ≡ -72(mod99) equal 27x ≡ 72(mod99) ?

Comment: The former: $27x \equiv -72$. $-72$ is the additive inverse of $72$ just like normal: that is, $72 + (-72) \equiv 0$. Modulo $99$, $-72$ also notates the same number that $27$ does. (Still working modulo $99$) $-72$ is also the same number as $(-1) * 72$, which is also the same number as $98 * 72$ (because $98 \equiv 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Add 9 to both sides to get
$$27x + 99 \equiv 27{ \rm mod} 99,$$
so now you  aare down to 
$$27x\equiv 27{ \rm mod} 99,$$
One quick solution is $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm mod\ 99\!:\ 27x\equiv 18\!-\!90\equiv 18\!+\!9\equiv 27\!\iff\! 99\mid 27(x\!-\!1)\!\iff\! 11\mid 3(x\!-\!1)\!\iff\! 11\mid x\!-\!1$